# Chrome in Ubuntu 21.10 only achieves video acceleration with VP9, not with H.264, resulting in higher CPU usage

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm checking with the developers tools, and with VP9 on youtube, I get Vpx decode, but with  H264, I get FFMpeg only.

I'm launching with the flags:

```
--ignore-gpu-blocklist --use-gl=desktop --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder
```

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome question.

Comment: It is a Chrome question, in Ubuntu. Because I had no such a problem in others operating systems.

Comment: So the problem is the version of Chrome being used in Ubuntu still a question for the Chrome people I think.

Comment: Well, I used the same version via the official .deb in all of my systems.
I'll ask in Chrome forums, but I don't have much hope that anyone care about linux to be honest.

Comment: Check if adding this option helps: `--disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder` I have added it to my `vivaldi` (chrome-based) and looks like it works.

Comment: Thanks! That did it, along with the usual flags.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved both VP9 and H.264 (lower CPU load), in Chrome 99 with:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --ignore-gpu-blocklist --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --use-gl=desktop --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder %U
```

Thanks Michal.

Comment: This worked for me! (chrome v100) and I have Ubuntu 21.10, and a laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 5850U with Radeon Graphics. `radeontop` shows unknown chip, but it shows a lot of usage when displaying video on youtube.

Comment: However, this does not work on my desktop machine with i5-6600K, geforce 1080ti, and ubuntu 22.04 with nvidia driver v510. Chrome does say `Video Decode: Hardware accelerated` but `nvtop` shows GPU is barely used, and CPU usage stays the same. Tested both X and Wayland.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be confused by the several decoder names.

VpxVideoDecoder is software decoding as well. You can easily verify this by pressing F12 while a VP9 video is played, to open Development Tools. Let it show the "Media" tab, and you will see "Hardware decoder: False" when VpxVideoDecoder is used.

Answer (score 1):

@KPrv's answer almost worked for me, just had to replace `--use-gl=desktop` with `--use-gl=egl`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288447)

Comment: @David it's as much of an answer as KPrv's.